# How can i use a javaScript variable in options_for_select While condition Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My javaScript Code for return variable from **id** or from **div**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function passParameters(modalvalues) {   var node_name =
    modalvalues.getAttribute("node_name");  
    $(".node-name").text(node_name);   $("#node_name").val(node_name); }
</script>
```

My code in Ruby:

```
<%= select_tag :relaunch, options_for_select(@restarts.where("node_name like
**javascriptnodeVariable**).collect {|u| [ "#{u.schedule_name}-#{u.node_name}", u.node_name ] }) %>
```

I was trying with that:

```
<%= select_tag :relaunch, options_for_select(@restarts.where("node_name like #{:id=>'node_name'}").collect {|u| [ "#{u.schedule_name}-#{u.node_name}", u.node_name ] }) %>
```

But i get this error:

```
C:/Sites/SIB/app/views/welcome/index.html.erb:495: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}' ...s.where("node_name like #{:id=>'node_name'}").collect {|u| [... ... ^
```

Thank you!

Comment: This error looks like an unclosed block (missing `}` or `end`)

Comment: Yes I thought the same, but if i replace the < :id =>'node_name'" > for a simple String its run. For this reason i want to know how i use the variable from "id" or "div" in the where condition

Comment: Please use the code formatting button to help format code properly